# Queryset inversa en modelos de Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Estoy tratando de acceder de forma inversa a un modelo.
Para acceder al modelo Vale consultando sobre el modelo DetalleVale es de la siguiente forma:

```
val= DetalleVale.objects.filter(vale__usuarioVale=usuario).filter(vale__statusFinalizado=1)
```

Sin embargo necesito consultar sobre el modelo Vale y a tráves de este llegar a las propiedades de DetalleVale
y poder hacer uso de los campos cartonNo, nombreM, parte etc

Mis modelos:

```
class Vale(models.Model):
 fechaCreacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 linea   = models.IntegerField(choices=LINEAS.CHOICES_LINEAS, default=LINEAS.SELECCIONAR)
 lote          = models.TextField(max_length=50)
 turno   = models.IntegerField(choices=TURNOS.CHOICES_TURNOS, default=TURNOS.SELECCIONAR)
 usuarioVale   = models.ForeignKey(User)
 statusFinalizado = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 statusAutorizacion=models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADOS.CHOICES_ESTADOS, default=ESTADOS.SELECCIONAR)
 vigenciaVale = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSVALE.CHOICES_STATUSVALE, default=STATUSVALE.ACTIVO)


class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Vales'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Vale'

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.id)

class DetalleVale(models.Model):
 fechaCreacion       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 vale                = models.ForeignKey(Vale)
 cartonNo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 nombreM = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
 parte       = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
 descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
 multiplo   = models.IntegerField()
 cantidad            = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo, simplemente tienes que seguir la relación inversa que has definido. Normalmente se puede nombrar esa relación con el nombre que quieras usando `related_name`:

```
class DetalleVale(models.Model):
 # ...
 vale                = models.ForeignKey(Vale, related_name='detalles')
 # ...
```

Cuando no defines el nombre explicitamente entonces la relación por defecto es una mezcla del nombre del modelo con la palabra `_set`. Como tu modelo se llama `DetalleVale` entonces la relación inversa creada por Django sería `detallevale_set`.

Teniendo esto claro, tu query puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
vales = Vale.objects.filter(
    detallevale_set__cartonNo='xxx'
    detallevale_set__nombreM='yyy'
    #...
)
for vale in vales:
    # hacer algo por aquí
```

De este modo obtienes todos los "Vales" cuyos detalles sean `xxx` para `cartonNo`, `yyy` para `nombreM`, etc.

Ojo, no necesitas anidar las llamadas al método `filter` para simular la condición `AND` en la base de datos ya que `AND` es la condición usada por defecto.

También te preguntarás qué es lo que hace internamente el ORM de Django al hacer ese tipo de queries. La respuesta es bastante sencilla: hace un `JOIN`.

Comment: Me dice que: Cannot resolve keyword 'detallevale_set' into field. Choices are:  detallevale    Que especifica set? detallevale_set__cartonNo

Comment: sin set, si me da el resultado queda así: detallevale__cartonNo

pero si quiero ingresar a los detalles con el for? es decir:

for vale in aprobados:
    print(vale.detallevale.parteUsi)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que mencionas no se puede hacer ya que al ser Vale fk de detallesVale si accedes desde vale a detallesVale te devolvera una lista, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
vales = Vale.objects.filter(.....) # añades los filtros que necesites
# con el siguiente for recorreras los detalles que pertenecen al modelo vale en cuestion
 for vale in vales:
     detalles = DetalleVale.objects.filter(vale=vale)
     for d in detalles:
        print d.nombreM
        print d.cartonNo
```

Comment: Me marca get() returned more than one Vale -- it returned 12!

Comment: Este caso que te planteo es si vale es un objeto y no una lista, cuando usas get los filtros te tienen que devolver un solo objeto sino te dará ese error. Quieres que cambie mi respuesta para el caso de que sea una lista?

Comment: Pero cuando le pongo filter me marca: 'Vale' object has no attribute 'detallevale' 
Le estoy filtrando estos campos:
vales= Vale.objects.filter(usuarioVale_id=usuario).filter(statusFinalizado=1).order_by('id').first()

Comment: Porque filter te devuelve una lista por lo tanto no puedes acceder directamente al atributo , voy a modificar mi respuesta usando filter

Comment: Prueba con el cambio que he hecho

Comment: No, ahora marca Exception Value:  

'Vale' object has no attribute 'detallevale'

Comment: Vale lío, he vuelto a modificar mi respuesta eso sí te funcionará

Comment: Si que funciona